# how to escape string in tcl with msys (mingw32)

Tags: bash, mingw, tcl, msys

I am trying to have tcl escape a string under MSys/MinGW (from mingw.org). The version of tcl comes from mingw.org (via mingw-get, as of Dec 2013).

In bash, I can do it for strings (simplified examples):

```
printf %q 'a \b $2'
printf '%q' "a \ b \' \" \$2"
```

which return:

```
a\ \\b\ \$2
a\ \\b\ \\\'\ \"\ \$2
```

respectively.

However, I can't make the second example work inside tclsh or tcl, if the string is stored in a variable or read from file. The things I tried are:

```
% set s {a \b ' "  $2}
% printf %q $s
/usr/bin/printf: %q: invalid conversion specification
child process exited abnormally
```

(I guess this is caused by the msys printf.exe not playing nicely with tclsh).

```
%exec bash -c "printf %q $s"
/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

(here, I don't even know how to properly quote $s, considering the single and double quotes inside $s). Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks

-- Update --

The answer @Donal Fellows works fine for the original string. I have:

```
% exec bash -c {printf %q "$0"} $s
a\ \\b\ \'\ \"\ \ \$2
```

But it didn't work for the test string I first encountered. The answer does not seem to work if there is an end-line in the string.

```
% set s1 {a \b ' "
 $2 }
% exec bash -c {printf %q "$0"} $s1
```

I was expecting something like:

```
a\ \\b\ \'\ \"\ \n\ \$2
```

Strangely, the above `exec` returns:

```
$'a \\b \' "  \n $2 '
```

which seems to be messed up. There is an unwanted leading `$'`, and the double quote `"` is not escaped properly. And blanks  are not escaped to `\` as before. Any ideas?

-- Update 2 --

As @Donal Fellows explained, the above string `$'a \\b \' "  \n $2 '` is a bash special form for quotation. One final question I have is on how to escape/make use of this special form in tcl. For example:

```
set s { ls
  echo '"' }
set ss [exec bash -c {printf %q "$0"} $s]
```

returns:

```
$' ls\n  echo \'"\' '
```

I could use this special form string in bash (msys/mingw):

```
eval $' ls\n  echo \'"\' '
```

which executes two lines of commands (ls and echo '"'), and returns, e.g.:

```
a.txt
"
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to make this work in tclsh.

```
% exec bash -c {eval $ss}
```

returns nothing at all. I tried a few other combinations. None worked. Any pointers on how to escape/unescape this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` is both a command in msys *and* a builtin in bash. **Only the bash builtin supports `%q`.** This means that invoking it from Tcl is rather more tricky than normal, as you've got to negotiate bash's quoting as well. This requires this rather awkward construction:

```
exec bash -c {printf %q "$0"} $s
```

The part *inside the braces* is shell syntax, but the rest is Tcl syntax; by doing it like this, it will work with (and so correctly shell-quote) *any* input. Note that Tcl's braces work just like bourne shell single quotes, except they're nestable.

---

If you then want to use the special form in bash, you then substitute it into the bash script *in Tcl*:

```
set quoted [exec bash -c {printf %q "$0"} $s]
exec bash -c "eval $quoted"
```

(This is OK. The `printf %q` does exactly the quoting to make this work; that's its purpose.)

If you've got a complicated script that will be using the quoted fragment where you don't want to do this, you end up with passing it in as an argument again and using another `eval` where necessary:

```
exec bash -c {
    # You can get *really* complicated in here!
    eval eval "$0"
} $quoted
```

But if this is going on, it might be time to consider whether your approach is the right one…

Comment: I've no idea why there's a separate command with the same name and inconsistent behaviour. Unix is like that sometimes, alas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works great on the original test string but breaks down if the string has an end-line character in it. Please see the update.

Comment: @TingL That's actually correct; bash has a `$'…'` special form, and it's legal for bash's `printf %q` to produce it.

Comment: While I'd never noticed that form before, it's definitely documented in the manual page. Apparently, [it's part of SUS issue 7](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed information. It's really helpful. I have one last question on the usage of the special form. Please see the update.